# ESP32: Power rail transient when using SPI on battery

Tags: batteries, current, spi, transient, esp32

Working on a small datalogger project using an ESP32-WROOOM that involves an analog sensor signal being recorded and saved to SD card. Having a big power rail spike issue that has been isolated down to the SPI. Setup is as follows:

1. Core → ESP32-WROOM
2. Power circuitry for USB and battery
3. Peripherals:

   a. Sensor (Analog input)

   b. ePaper screen (SPI)

   c. SD card (SPI)

Channel 1 (yellow) is the 3.3V rail, Channel 2 (Blue) is the SPI clock:
[image: Channel 1 (yellow) is the 3.3V rail, Channel 2 (Blue) is the SPI clock.]

**Note:**

This issue only occurs when the setup is powered on a 3.7V 1200mAh LiPo battery.

There is no WiFi or Bluetooth in use.

Circuit has been decoupled with bulk caps.

**USB:** Stable 3v3 and no power dips/ spikes appear during the record procedure.

**BATTERY:** When the code enters record mode there are significant power dips on the 3v3 rail that appear to be caused by the SPI (SCLK & MOSI).

The only difference between the power input circuitry is that the battery circuit utilises a power trench mosfet whereas the USB goes through a shottky diode.

This is how power gets into the circuit:
[image: This is how power gets into the circuit]

The power rail spikes are affecting the 3v3 rail to the extent that the sensor readings are getting completely messed up.

Wondering if anyone has experienced something similar? Sense is that it is a battery/ current limiting issue or something to do with the ESP32.

Closer views of the noise spikes:
[image: Closer views of the noise spikes]

Comment: Is your PMOS a logic level FET? Seeing   power rail excursions on fast edges may be due to layout or probing indictance. Also, your 3V3 regulator needs to be an LDO.

Comment: I believe you have a starving 3.3V regulator, have you tried replacing the 100k pull-down (on PMOS gate) to 10k instead?

Comment: @sstobbe The PMOS is logic level and we are using a LDO... The artefacts are still present when we're not probing, but I'm curious to know what in the layout could cause this? It occours on both the PCB and breadboard versions of the circuit.

Comment: Does your PCB have a solid ground plane? You have 2 separate issues. The excursions on SPI CLK/DAT edges are due to wiring inductance and perhaps lack of bypass capacitors. Your 3V3 rail should not be sagging/wondering by 200 mV over a period of 100 us. Can you probe just the 3V3 rail with a probe with a spring ground clip?

Comment: there is a solid ground plane (it's a 4 layer PCB). Pretty much everything uses decoupling caps, and we tried putting some from the SPI lines to ground with no effect... We probed the 3V3 rail with a spring and it looks exactly the same on the scope

Comment: @nappleton Have you tried the 10k on the PMOS gate? Have you tried bypassing the PMOS to feed the regulator?

Comment: @Cisco25 yeah we tried the 10k, didn't seem to help. I just tried shorting the PMOS (source and drain) to no avail :/

Comment: @nappleton Is your power supply current limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the advice you guys have given, it turns out @Cisco25 was right and the PMOS was starving the 3.3V reg. When shorted the battery straight into the regulator on our PCB, it did remove all of these artefacts. (don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried it, but there ya go)

We also added a 1nF cap at the input of the reg and a bypass cap on the 100k resistor which seemed to help (thouh when we shorted the PMOS this was made redudant).